# Understanding how values are being passed to a SQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL.

Someone shared with me this function

```
with driver_documents_lookup as
(
select
    item_display_name,
    is_satisfied(
        'driver_document',
        requirement_type_enum,
        state,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        expiration_date := expiration_date
    ) as satisfied

from all_requirements_driver_documents
where driver_id = 'VDi9jqE2'
)
```

Here, I didn't comprehend how do we determine what is `requirement_type_enum` and `state`. like what values are being passed to it/how is it setup.

Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: `requirement_type_enum` is a column in the table `all_requirements_driver_documents`

Comment: Right, and columns of tables in the `FROM` clause can be used in expressions in the `SELECT` clause of a query.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a function.  It is an *incomplete fragment of* an SQL query. (It might also be a fragment of a function, as functions can have embedded SQL.)

"requirement_type_enum" and "state" are probably columns in the table "all_requirements_driver_documents".  But if that SQL is embedded inside a function, then those might instead be variables or parameters of that function.